# Dynamic component within a loop (passing template to function)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically create a component within a loop. The problem I am facing, is that I cannot pass the template to the function to create the component. It is saying that `viewContainer` is `undefined`.

> Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

```js
export class DataEditModalComponent {
  public fields = [
    { component: ComponentA },
    { component: ComponentB }
  ]

  public constructor(private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  public createComponent(component: any, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <ng-template #template *ngIf="field.component && createComponent(field.component, template)">
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all: don't execute such kind of functions in template. Second observation is that #template reference is not available in ngIf because it's inner variable. Third comment is that #template refers to TemplateRef not to ViewContainerRef

Comment: Binding a function to a directive within a loop - looks like a very bad idea if you're using default CD strategy. The function will be triggered for each CD cycle and for each element of the array.

Comment: What would be a better alternative? Would a pipe work in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how it might be implemented:

**Component**:

```
public fields = [
  { component: ComponentA },
  { component: ComponentB }
]

components = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.components = this.fields.filter(x => x.component).map(x => x.component)
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of components" [ngComponentOutlet]="c"></ng-container>
```

Comment: This has been working well, Is there anyway to pass input data to the component?